# jQuery internal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalHours = 0;
    $('select').each(function(sel)
    {                
      totalHours += parseFloat($(sel).val());
    });
    alert(totalHours);
});
```

So I expect to see the total of the values of the `<select>` elements on the page, but instead I get this error in jQuery (it occurs on the line inside the `each` loop). Why would I be getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().each` https://api.jquery.com/each/

> Type: `Function( Integer index, Element element )`
>
> A function to execute for each matched element.

The function signature is `(index, element)` but you're using it as `(element)` - change to

```
$('select').each(function(i, sel)
```

Updated code:

```js
var totalHours = 0;
$('select').each(function(i, sel) {
  totalHours += parseFloat($(sel).val());
});
console.log(totalHours);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or, as @Phong pointed out, use `this` (not added to my answer to keep it a separate answer, but either is equally viable)

Answer (score 1):

You should change from `$(sel).val()` to `$(this).val()` like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalHours = 0;
    $('select').each(function()
    {                
      totalHours += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    alert(totalHours);
});
```